# Why const_cast in an overloaded function?

Tags: c++

Chapter 6.4 of the book C++ Primer states the following:

> In § 4.11.3 (p. 163) we noted that `const_cast`s are more useful in the context of overloaded functions. As one example, recall our `shorterString` function from § 6.3.2 (p. 224):

```
const string &shorterString(const string &s1, const string &s2)
{
    return s1.size() <= s2.size() ? s1 : s2;
}
```

> This function takes and returns references to `const string`. We can call the function on a pair of non`const string` arguments, but we'll get a reference to a `const string` as the result. We might want to have a version of `shorterString` that, when given non`const` arguments, would yield a plain reference. We can write this version of our function using a `const_cast`:

```
string &shorterString(string &s1, string &s2)
{
    auto &r = shorterString(const_cast<const string &>(s1), const_cast<const string &>(s2));
    return const_cast<string&>(r);
}
```

> This version calls the `const` version of `shorterString` by casting its arguments to references to `const`. That function returns a reference to a `const string`, which we know is bound to one of our original, non`const` arguments. Therefore, we know it is safe to cast that `string` back to a plain `string&` in the return.

My question: what would be the benefit of this method, as opposed to the code below? Wouldn't the performance suffer because of the function call? Or is this just a bad example?

```
string &shorterString(string &s1, string &s2) {
    return s1.size() <= s2.size() ? s1 : s2;
}
```

Comment: The main benefit is avoiding code duplication, the function could have a lot more code in it. *"Wouldn't the performance suffer"* In a release build I expect there to be no difference.

Comment: How is the title related to what you are really asking? I reckon that you're simply trying to understand the motivation of function overloading.

Answer (score 3):

This example is misleading because the initial function in this case is so short and simple there is little advantage to the approach over a second full definition as you proposed.

The thought is that you want two version of the function, one that has const arguments and return and one with reference arguments and return.  It is not a great example because the overload function is just as long as the initial function.

If you assume the initial `shorterString` function is instead fairly complex, the overloaded function would still only be a couple lines to convert reference arguments to const and the return const to a reference.  By taking this approach you can have two different argument/return behaviors with proper reuse instead of duplicated code.